# Proof by induction on binary trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

Right now I'm currently working on a problem in my algorithm design textbook, and I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

The problem is:

> A binary tree is a rooted tree in which each node has at most two
>   children. Show by induction that in any binary tree that the number of
>   nodes with two children is exactly one less than the number of leaves.

I'm reasonably certain of how to do this: the base case has a single node, which means that the tree has one leaf and zero nodes with two children. However, I'm not quite certain exactly what the inductive step would entail.

Comment: Are you asking what a proof by induction is, or what the proof by induction is for this particular task?

Comment: @MooingDuck I already know what a proof by induction is, I'm just not sure what the actual proof would be. I know how to prove the base case P(1), as I said, but I can't figure out to prove p(n + 1) for some n.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A tree with a single node with no children (obviously), has/is one leaf.  The number of nodes with two children (0) is exactly one less than the number of leaves (1).

Adding a node to an existing node that has no children, does not change the number of nodes with two children, nor the number of leaves.

Adding a node to an existing node that has one child, increases the number of nodes with two children by 1, and also increases the number of leaves by 1.

You cannot add a node to an existing node with any other number of children.

Since the number of nodes with two children starts as exactly one less than the number of leaves, and adding a node to the tree either changes neither number, or increases both by exactly one, then the difference between them will always be exactly one.

Comment: Awesome. It cleared my all doubt. All I was doing is was hitting my head to understand handshake lemma.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have been able to solve it either, until the OP said "inductive". That usually means "prove the thing is true for an easy node", and "prove that the thing is true for a node that's adjacent to a true node", and then you're done. I simply followed those steps.

Answer (score 1):

With induction on the number of nodes with 2 children :

Base - 0 nodes with 2 children - 1 leaf (assuming the root is not counted as one).
Step - Let T be a tree with n+1 > 0 nodes with 2 children

=> there is a node a with 2 children a1, a2 and in the subtree rooted in a1 or a2 there are no nodes with 2 children. we can assume it's the subtree rooted in a1.

=> remove the subtree rooted in a1, we got a tree T' with n nodes with 2 children.

=> T' has n+1 leaves.

=> add the subtree rooted in a1 to T' - we added one leaf and one node with 2 children.

There are some holes that you need to complete, but it's working.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

So, for a Binary Tree with at most 2 children, there can be three possibilities:

1. Nodes with two children; let m
2. Nodes with one children; let n
3. Nodes with no children that is leaf nodes; let k

For counting all the nodes of the tree, we will be counting the  number of children of all the three type of nodes. Therefore,

Total nodes accounting to child of a parent node having 2 children is 2*m.

Total nodes accounting to child of a parent node having 1 child is n.

Total nodes accounting to child of a parent node having 0 child is 0.

Total nodes: 2*m + n + 1.. (1) (adding 1 for the root as it is the only node with no parent)

Also Total nodes = m + n + k.. (2)

Equating these 2 equations,

k = m + 1

=> No of leaf nodes is one more than the number of nodes having two child nodes.